# Array two dimension on C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i want write the array two dimension contains this :

can you please tell me if this it's OK

```
String [] color=new String("Rouge","Vert","Blanc","Noir","Gris");
String [] article=new String("chaise","table","pvc","tapis","Visual");
String[,] choix = New String[,];
choix[color[0],article[0]]='350,25';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: just try out what happens when you execute it. Why should we test what you could easily find out yourself?

Comment: Perhaps if you started with valid C# code the compiler might help you to work out what you need to write?

Comment: Start off by declaring an array of strings this way: `string[] colors = new string[] { "Rouge", "Vert", ... };`.

Comment: Why do you want to use a two-dimensional array? They are often quite difficult to work with. A jaggard array is better. In your case that's a `string[][]` rather than a `string[,]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```
public class ColorArticle
{
    public string color { get; set; }

    public string article { get; set; }

}

public void SetChoice()
{
    ColorArticle colorArticle = new ColorArticle() { color = "Rouge", article = "chaise" };

    Dictionary<ColorArticle, string> listChoice = new Dictionary<ColorArticle, string>
    {
        { colorArticle, "350,25" }
    };
}
```

Comment: And where is the `350,25`-part?

Comment: Have you ever tried using `string[]` as a key for a dictionary?

Comment: Well, I'd do something entirely different, but that's what he wants so..

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim - But it doesn't work. Arrays are only equal by reference. So you can never reconstruct the key unless you use the original key reference. That totally negates the value of a dictionary.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that, i edited the answer to something he could use.